# Error compiling caffe on Mac OS

Tags: caffe, libstdc++, pycaffe, libc++

I compiled caffe successfully at first and tried the MNIST example. But there is something wrong when I tried to install pycaffe. So I reinstalled caffe. However I received compiling error this time.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

After I input the command 'clang -v'

```
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Did you uninstall pycaffe as well?  If not, check your environment variables (e.g. PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH) for precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was the problem between two version of python. The system default version and the anaconda one. You have to make sure the compiling and executing using the same one.